# error in sharepoint 2010 designer while saving:"Content in the embedded form may be changed by the the server to remove unsafe content. "

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am doing development in SharePoint 2010.
If I create a site page with the SharePoint look and feel for that site on save, I am getting this error:** "Content in the embedded form may be changed by the server to remove unsafe content. Do you want to reload your page to see the results of the save? "** and when I say reload, the server removes some parts of my page, e.g., onclick event of html, asp buttons.

I took a copy of 'How To Read Library' page just edited the text part of that page, and when I try to save this error again comes up.

However, if I create a simple aspx page with only html tags like head body, then there is no problem, everything works great. But SharePoint look and feel pages are giving troubles while saving.

Has anybody seen this previously? What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Are you using HTML tags or JavaScript in your content fields? This might trigger that behaviour

Answer (score 2):

Which template did you use?  I've had this same problem using the wiki site template, and found this link indicating you should use the blank site template:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/af116ce7-ba3b-4722-9d5e-6321ea323448

However, I'd hope there's a better solution