# Sharepoint 2010 - stopping unsafe code removal

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, unsafe

I am creating a Sharepoint 2010 site, and I am finding that after editing HTML in Sharepoint Designer, on saving some code is likely to be removed: "Content in the embedded form may be changed by the the server to remove unsafe content". This is typically where a  tag references javascript, eg ... href="javascript:somefunction()" ... . The href disappears completely.

No doubt it has its reasons, but this is a closed system and I need the code there. How do I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop that. If you really want to bypass that you'll have to come up with some workaround, like using jQuery to forcefully insert your "unsafe" content in the page.

**EDIT:** Someone has had the same problem as you in another question here in Stack Overflow. If you're using the wiki template, your answer may as well be there:

[error in sharepoint 2010 designer while saving:"Content in the embedded form may be changed by the the server to remove unsafe content. "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895880/error-in-sharepoint-2010-designer-while-savingcontent-in-the-embedded-form-may)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I had just belatedly noticed that but was hoping there was some solution for wiki pages. It seems not. Microsoft knows best, of course.

Comment: Yes, the wiki page to blank page change worked, but the code still won't run. I am trying to instantiate a WScript.Shell object in a java script function. The code works fine in an HTML file just loaded into the browser, but when the same code it put into the Sharepoint master page, on the same browser it says "couldn't instantiate object". This is very strange given that it is all client side, and it is the same broswer?

Comment: Not strange it all. Javascript is not intuitive and easy as people make it seem. You should create another question, speficic to this new issue you are encountering. Don't forget to include as much detail about the error as you can. The browser's console will help you there.